# Is this possible with linq using private setters?

Tags: c#, linq, immutability

With a parent and child setup like this: Where the parent has a list of children.

```
public sealed class Parent
{
    public Parent(DateTime recordTime, int randomValue, bool isAccepted, List<Child> children)
    {
        RecordTime = recordTime;
        RandomValue = randomValue;
        IsAccepted = isAccepted;
        Children = adjustments;
    }

    public DateTime RecordTime { get; private set; }
    public int RandomValue { get; private set; }
    public bool IsAccepted { get; private set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class Child
{
    public Child(int randomChildValue, bool isPositive, Parent parent)
    {
        RandomChildValue = randomChildValue;
        IsPositive = isPositive;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public int RandomChildValue { get; private set; }
    public bool IsPositive { get; private set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

Using the LINQ Select extension method to project the parent and children based on other collections. How can I pass the parent item to the child. I know I can get the index of the parent using `.Select((x,index) => new Parent....` In the below linq statement I am passing null, but is it possible to pass the parent?

```
var parentCollection = neighborCollection.Select(x => new Parent(x.Time, (int)x.ItemsProcessed, x.UserAccepted, 
                          x.subCollection.Select(y => new Child((int)y.Sub, y.IsPositive, null)).ToList()));
```

Comment: You're missing some code here. What is `neighborCollection` and `x.subCollection`?

Comment: They are separate types used to build the parent and children.  So I am selecting from the neighbor collection to build the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make your parent constructor assign itself as the parent to each of the children.  However since Parent is private, you will have to regenerate your child list in the parent constructor

```
Children = children.Select(c => new Child(c.RandomChildValue, c.IsPositive, this)).ToList()
```

Comment: I would have to change the setters or create a new Collection.

Comment: no?   ```Children = children.Select(c => new Child(c.RandomChildValue, c.IsPositive, this).ToList()```